# Using nested beginform in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have scenario where I have load data on dropdown selection change and after manipulation I have to submit the page for saving.

I have developed the page but since I new to MVC so can anyone verify me code and can suggest better approach of doing the same.

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "forecast"))
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("YearChange", "forecast", FormMethod.Get, new {@id="frmYearChange" }))
    {
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="well well-sm" style="padding-bottom: 0px !important;">
                <div class="span5">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="selectGroup">
                            Select Group:</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.groupId, Model.groupList, "--Select Group--", new { @id = "selectGroup" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span5">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="selectYear">
                            Select Year:</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.yearId, Model.yearList, "--Select Year--", new { @id = "selectYear", onchange = "selectYear_indexChanged();" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix">
                    &nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
.....
}
```

Comment: I dont think you can have nested forms 


[Check this link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms

Comment: You could either have two pages, one with the drop downs which when submitted, returns the second page/form.  OR instead when submitting the dropdown values, you do an AJAX submit and replace the current form with the result of an action returning a PartialView containing the second form, or replace a div placeholder below the current form with the new form so that you have two forms above/below instead of nested.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have nested forms. You can however have multiple forms per view.
See [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/forms.html#the-form-element) for more info.